# Testcomplete Javascript - Printing the output of SQL query

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I am trying to output the value that changed after executing an SQL query (successfully executed outside of this script, manually). So that I can do a checkpoint to validate that the query executed as expected. I am a beginner

So far I have try two things :

Method that I tried #1- in a COMMON FILE / FUNCTION

#

```
function Execute_SQLQuery_GetField(queryString, vServer, fieldName)
{
    var query = queryString;

    var Qry = ADO.CreateADOQuery();
    Qry.ConnectionString = GetDBAConnectionString(vServer);

    Qry.SQL=query;
    Qry.Open();
    Qry.First();
    var value = Qry.FieldByName(fieldName).Value;
    Qry.Close();

    return value;
}
```

Script calling the "Execute_SQLQuery_GetField" function:

#

```
function test(){
        var query = "select SECURITY, SECUFIRME, SYMBOLE, DESC_L1, DESC_L2, CATEGO, RISK_RATING from b_titre where RISK_RATING !=null";
        var fieldName = "RISK_RATING"

        var output = Execute_SQLQuery_GetField(query, vServerTitre, fieldName)
        Log.Message(output())


}
```

I also tried this- Method #2 :

in a COMMON FILE / FUNCTION

#

```
function Execute_SQLQuery_GetFieldAllValues(queryString, vServer, fieldName)
{
    var query = queryString;

    var Qry = ADO.CreateADOQuery();
    Qry.ConnectionString = GetDBAConnectionString(vServer);

    Qry.SQL=query;
    Qry.Open();
    Qry.First();

    var arrayOfValues = new Array();
    while (!Qry.EOF){
        arrayOfValues.push(Qry.FieldByName(fieldName).Value);
        Qry.Next();
    }
    Qry.Close();

    return arrayOfValues;
}
```

Script calling the "Execute_SQLQuery_GetField" function:

#

```
function test(){
        var query = "select SECURITY, SECUFIRME, SYMBOLE, DESC_L1, DESC_L2, CATEGO, RISK_RATING from b_titre where RISK_RATING !=null";
        var fieldName = "RISK_RATING"

        var output = Execute_SQLQuery_GetFieldAllValues(query, vServerTitre, fieldName)
        Log.Message(output())


}
```

So basically, I first executed the query manually. Then using the script, I would like to confirm that it got executed successfully by printing put the value that changed.

I know the code above has problems but I'm not making much progress.

UPDATE:

I also tried putting everything in a single function and add multiple Log.Message. This is what it looks like: (still not working)

```
function test(){
        var query = "select SECURITY, SECUFIRME, SYMBOLE, DESC_L1, DESC_L2, CATEGO, RISK_RATING from b_titre where RISK_RATING!=null";
        var fieldName = "RISK_RATING"


    Log.Message("1---------------------------")
    var Qry = ADO.CreateADOQuery();
    Qry.ConnectionString = GetDBAConnectionString(vServerTitre);

    Qry.SQL=query;
    Qry.Open();
    Qry.First();
    Log.Message("2---------------------------")

    var arrayOfValues = new Array();
    while (!Qry.EOF){
        Log.Message("3---------------------------")
        Log.Message(Qry.FieldByName(fieldName).Value)
        arrayOfValues.push(Qry.FieldByName(fieldName).Value);
        Qry.Next();
    }
    Qry.Close();

    Log.Message( arrayOfValues.Length)




}
```

The output logs :

```
log   1---------------------------  9:27:20 Normal          0.00
log   2---------------------------  9:27:20 Normal          0.41
log   empty
```

Comment: The code doesnt match what is being called, in the function you have it called Execute_SQLQuery_GetField but in the calling code you are calling a different method Execute_SQLQuery_GetFieldAllFields  where is the code for the AllFields method?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the code. I tried two methods but I still don't get the expected result

Comment: I was reviewing the post as it is your first post on the site, Welcome to the site by the way. Once you have been on the site a while with good enough rating you will also be asked to review others first posts and first answers, Sorry i am not a javascript expert so no idea on how to resolve your issue, although it looks like nothing will have changed, the calls in both cases are selects not updates so no records have changed, are you missing a step in your example?

Comment: Also the query is all encompassing, wouldnt the query look better as
        var fieldName = "RISK_RATING"

var query = "select "+fieldname+"from b_titre where RISK_RATING !=null";

Comment: I added another situation that I tried but still not working. I do not know how to make the sql query look better. This is my first time dealing with SQL, Testcomplete or Javascript

Comment: Also, the initial sql command was executed manually before running this script. (because in this script, I am trying to print the values that changed using Log.Message) that is why I use SELECT

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

problematic line was:

```
var query = "select SECURITY, SECUFIRME, SYMBOLE, DESC_L1, DESC_L2, CATEGO, RISK_RATING from b_titre where RISK_RATING!=null";
```

adding two single quote fixed my issue:

```
var query = "select SECURITY, SECUFIRME, SYMBOLE, DESC_L1, DESC_L2, CATEGO, RISK_RATING from b_titre where RISK_RATING!='null'";
```